# pdf ebook reader for iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, ebook-reader

pdf's are fixed and not reflow able. I have to develop an ebook reader supporting pdf format and add as much functionality in it as possible.

1)    I wanted to ask if functionalities like night mode, font face and size changing possible ? if yes then how ?

2)    I wanted to know in depth details about pdf ebooks and the meta data related to them ? how does acrobat reader knows the chapter titles of the different chapters in ebook (how the metadata is stored and how does it read it ?

3)    How does acrobat reader perform the search through pdfs ?

4)    i'll be developing the same using quartz framework instead of uiwebview. Is there any other way that is better ? Any suggestions regarding the same

Apart from these, please add any other information you think that might be useful for me to develop the same.

Thanks

Comment: I'am pretty sure here no one is going to answer you. The question is too broad..

Comment: There also seems to be some confusion about "e-book" and "PDF". The OP seems to assume "you can read both with iBook therefore PDF ≡ e-pub". **iBooks** (the application) shows 'chapter titles of the different chapters', but only for `.epub` files. It does not, and can not, do so for PDF files.

Comment: (Does anyone know where the idiomatic use of the phrase "the same" comes from?)

Comment: am not sure about the iBook but there are apps which can show table of contents extracted from the pdf metadata...CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog;

i know the question is too broad, i just expect to get answer regarding any point written above...

Comment: As it has been said, there is a difference between an ebook and a PDF document. So, it should be clarified for which file format that viewer should work.

Comment: FWIW, reflow is possible with PDF. UNDER THE CONDITION that the PDF is a "structured PDF", meaning that the PDF document has complete structure information embedded. Structured PDFs are necessary, for example, for working properly with screen readers.

One can therefore say, that if the PDF document is PDF/UA compliant, it will reflow.

Comment: On another note, the latest version of a software called "Acrobat Reader" is more than 10 years old. The free PDF viewer by Adobe is called "Adobe Reader".

Comment: ebooks can have a format that varies from epub, pdf, mobipocket, text , html and many others...so when i say an ebook reader supporting pdf format, it should be clear enough...

Comment: @Jongware brother..it can show chapter titles for pdf also...i've seen it in many apps as well as able to script in mine too

Comment: @Anil if u have any idea about the night mode and font change pls mention it briefly. As of now am planning to drop the idea for night mode and font face and size as i know how complicated it is to alter with the file structure of pdf. apart from that i see know other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For TOC, google vfr / reader (the project is also on github)...there is a class readerdocumentoutline.h ....u'll get to know the implementation of table of contents...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: of course this is not a complete solution but for those who are facing a similar problem, this'll provide them with a gigantic help

Comment: Yes, maybe it helps. I wouldn't have left that comment if you were not only posting a "google this and that" post but an actual brief of what you will find when searching for these things.

Comment: the class that i mentioned is the solution...and u don't have to search randomly...the project is there, the class is there

https://github.com/vfr/Reader/blob/master/Sources/ReaderDocumentOutline.m

i can't spoon feed the answer now...because i already have

Comment: you see? you have a link here:)